# What is the right way to explain this code?

Tags: c, string, pointers

Shouldn't **st** be a array of pointers to char rather than a pointer to char? I do not understand how the latter `for loop` prints the value?

```
int main(void)
{
    char temp[256]; 
    char *st;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
       scanf("%s", temp);
       st= strdup(temp);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        printf("%s",st);
    }    
}
```

Comment: "Shouldn't strings be a array of pointers to char rather than a pointer to char? "Absolutely not, at least in C. In C strings are represented as *arrays of characters* with terminating null-characters at the end of strings.

Comment: A string can be either an array of characters or a pointer to the first character. Why would you need an array of pointers to characters? Are you imagining a string where each character might be in a completely different memory location?

Comment: One would expect a string to be in a continuous memory region, thus only a pointer to the first character is enough, all other letters are between that point and the next '\0' character. Right? :)

Comment: @MikeCAT i think u misunderstood my question from strings i'm referring to the that pointer which I declared in this code. anyways i edited it u can check it now

Comment: Now `strings` is undeclared. Also you should include proper headers to use library functions.

Comment: `st` can be anything because it is unused.

Comment: I shouldn't be declaring it using name `strings`.  Sorry people :(

Comment: What you should do depends on what you want to do. By the way, causing memory leak by throwing the return value of `strdup` away doesn't seem a good idea.

Comment: @Ria You don't explain *why* you think there should be an array of pointers to characters. Are you imagining that each character in the string might be stored at a completely different memory location? Also, you don't explain what output you get or what input you are giving. So it's hard to figure out what you mean by "I do not understand how the latter for loop prints the value?". What value are you talking about?

Comment: To clarify @DavidSchwartz, I'm pretty sure he's saying "non-contiguous memory locations". They are obviously at "different" locations.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer The only reason you would need a pointer to each character would be if each character were at *completely* different memory location. You could implement a string that way if you really wanted to, but it would be ridiculously inefficient.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I know that. I was thinking of Ria reading your "completely different" and not getting what you meant.

Comment: @Ria what are you _actually_ trying to achieve ?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz It looks as though the OP meant an array of pointers ... to different strings, not an array of pointers ... to characters within one string. As the posted code shows, the single pointer `*st` is repeatedly overwritten, hence the need for an array of pointers (at least with this structure of separate for loops)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char temp[256]; 
    char *st[3];     // array of three pointers to char

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
       scanf("%255s", temp);   // prevents potential buffer overflow
       st[i] = strdup(temp);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", st[i]);
        free(st[i]);           // free strduped memory
    }
}
```

This program displays:

> ./a.out
>   11
>   22
>   33
>   11
>   22
>   33

Whereas your program displays

> ./a.out
>   11
>   22
>   33
>   33
>   33
>   33

this is because:

```
char *st;        // in your prog. you only declare one pointer

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
   scanf("%s", temp);
   st= strdup(temp);   // here you overwrite the st pointer loosing
                       // the string strduped in the previous run of the loop
}
```

Comment: @Ria in your program you have `printf("%s",st);` inside the `for` loop. So it's quite normal that it prints the same string 3 times. If you had `printf("Hello");` inside the `for` loop, it would print 3 times "Hello".